# What is the current best way to wrap console.log() that will preserve line numbers?

Tags: javascript

I've previously used the following based on other SO answers (without really understanding the need for (nor the workings of) the `prototype.apply.apply`

```
var mylogger = {
    log: function () {
        if (window.console) {
            if (window.console.log) {
                Function.prototype.apply.apply(console.log, [console, arguments]);
            }
        }
    },
    ...
};
```

while this prevents IE from crapping on itself, it also make the line number reporting unusable (it always reports the `apply.apply..` line.

I was playing around a little and discovered that the following seems to do exactly what I need, i.e. prevent IE from crapping on itself and report the line number where `mylogger.log(..)` was called from..

```
var mylogger = {
    // function invocation returning a safe logging function..
    log: (function () {
        if (window.console && window.console.log && Function.prototype.bind) {
            return window.console.log.bind(window.console);
        } else {
            return function () {};
        }
    }()),
    ...
};
```

I've done some basic testing on IE/FF/Chrome without seeing any issues.. is this reasonable or is there a better way?

Comment: Blasphemy, remove this question at once! Internet Explorer does not crap it self, it was create by the Almighty Bill, and is probably the finest web equipment ever made by man, even if Bill is more godlike than most mere mortals. We will not stand for any criticism of the only true and just browser currently available.

Comment: Current versions of IE are quite heavenly to work with ;-)

Comment: Indeed, my long time favorite is version 6, which is a delight compared to such monstrosities as Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Our contracts specify last 3 versions of IE, so we've just dropped support for IE8 (*yay*) :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing is fine I guess, but if you aren't adding any additional functionality, you could do something simple and in one line:

```
window.console = (window.console || {debug:function(){},log:function(){},error:function(){}});
```

You could, of course, add other `console` functions if you use them.

Comment: Cute, you're overriding the `window.console` object instead of the `window.console.log` function. I suppose I could do `var mylogger = (window.console || ...);` to preserve my interface..

Comment: @thebjorn This is not overriding actually, this is just a fallback to a no op api : `console = console OR noopapi`. This will prevent consoleless browsers from crashing when trying to access the console api : `ReferenceError : console is not defined`.

Comment: Yeah, and just to be clear why I do that versus override `window.console.log` itself: some browsers (IE10, maybe others) mark `window.console` as an immutable object, thus you get an error trying to override any of its methods. Replacing the entire object gets around this.